# In Dart program, logger package does not print to console neither when run as "dart my_server.dart" nor when running the compiled version

Tags: dart, logging, console

I am working on a server-side script in Dart and using  ([logger package](https://stackoverflow.com)). When I run the app within the IDE, logging works like a charm but if I run the script from command line:

```
dart my_server.dart
```

nothing gets printed at the console. I tried compiling the server and the results are the same: nothing gets printed.

I tried replacing the default printing class:

```
class ConsoleOutput extends LogOutput {
  @override
  void output(OutputEvent event) {
    for (var line in event. Lines) {
      print(line);
    }
  }
}
```

by

```
class ConsoleOutput extends LogOutput {
  @override
  void output(OutputEvent event) {
    for (var line in event.lines) {
      stdout.write(line);
    }
  }
}
```

because my understanding is that "print" does not get included in the executable, but nothing gets printed either. Edit: wrong info. print IS included in the executable.

My setup is:

```
var logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
      methodCount: 2,
      // number of method calls to be displayed
      errorMethodCount: 8,
      // number of method calls if stacktrace is provided
      lineLength: 120,
      // width of the output
      colors: true,
      // Colorful log messages
      printEmojis: false,
      // Print an emoji for each log message
      printTime: true // Should each log print contain a timestamp
  ),
  output: ConsoleOutput(),
);
```

and

```
void main() {
  Logger.level = Level.trace;
```

**Once again, inside the IDE everything works as expected.** What am I missing?

Thank in advance.
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit in the source code, I found one solution: using PoductionFilter() as a filter does the trick.
Then, after reading the documentation for the third time I noticed a had overlooked the simplest solution: just use filter:

```
class MyFilter extends LogFilter {
  @override
  bool shouldLog(LogEvent event) {
    return true;
  }
}
```